# is there any quick function to do looking-back calculating in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna implement a calculate method like **a simple scenario**:

> value computed as the sum of daily data during the previous N days (set N = 3 in the following example)

Dataframe df:  (df.index is 'date')

```
date  value  
20140718  1  
20140721  2     
20140722  3     
20140723  4     
20140724  5     
20140725  6     
20140728  7  
......
```

to do calculating like:

```
date  value  new  
20140718  1  0  
20140721  2  0      
20140722  3  0  
20140723  4  6 (3+2+1)  
20140724  5  9 (4+3+2)  
20140725  6  12 (5+4+3)     
20140728  7  15 (6+5+4) 
......
```

Now I have done this using for cycle like:

```
df['value']=[0]*len(df)
for idx in df.index  
    loc=df.index.get_loc(idx)
    if((loc-N)>=0):
        tmp=df.ix[df.index[loc-3]:df.index[loc-1]]
        sum=tmp['value'].sum()
    else:
        sum=0
    df['new'].ix(idx)=sum
```

But, when the length of dataframe or the value of N is very long / big, these calculating will be very slow....How I can implement this faster using a function or by other ways?
Besides, if the scenario is more complex? how ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for [rolling functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments)?

Comment: yes,thanks, it is a better one. I will try rolling_apply in a complex scenario

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the sum of the previous three excluding the current one, you can use `rolling_apply`  over the a window of four and sum up all but the last value.

```
new = rolling_apply(df, 4, lambda x:sum(x[:-1]), min_periods=4)
```

This is the same as shifting afterwards with a window of three:

```
new = rolling_apply(df, 3, sum, min_periods=3).shift()
```

Then

```
df["new"] = new["value"].fillna(0)
```

Comment: thank you. I am a python junior, rolling_xxxx function which you told me helped me a lot